# Dynamo db sorting

Tags: amazon-web-services, nosql, amazon-dynamodb, secondary-indexes

I have a scenario in which I will have to list the incoming requests of a user sorted based on creation time and priority(High, Medium, Low) along with pagination. Is there a way to achieve this in dynamoDb ?

Right now I'm using a secondary Index like userId-createdAt-index which sorts data based on creation time and further sorting the request based on priority separately in the frontend. Somebody please provide a right solution for this.

Comment: Can you add few more details? Like sample data or something.

Comment: Primary Key : requestId, GSI : {partition key : userId, sort key : createdAt}, Other attributes are : Priority(Possible values : High, Medium, Low), updatedAt. Here I need to sort based on creation time and after that ordered by priority.

Comment: I doubt you want to sort by date/time and then by priority. That would simply sort by date/time in practice because, generally speaking, no two records would have the same timestamp.

Answer (score 0):

You're correct to use an index with a sort key. This could also be your primary index, thus reducing how many indexes you need, but that of course depends on whether you already have a sort key on your primary.

DDB guarantees the order of a sorted index, so paging will correctly page by date for you, if you want to reverse the order, add the `ScanIndexForward` to your query and set it to `false`.

Your model of query / sort by date at the DB level, then sort by other fields at the application level is normal and correct.

Depending very much on your use-case, another option to consider is querying by priority by using `KeyConditions` and adding the condition `#priority EQ :priority`, but I doubt this is what you want.